# Java : Cancel a running process( or task) by clicking a button in webapplication in spring

Tags: java, ajax, spring, tomcat

I submitted a request in my web application which may take long time to process the request and get response. Is there any way user can cancel the request in the middle by clicking a button in the web application.

Aborting the ajax request will not stop the request in the server side.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Why would a user want to cancel a request?

If it's long running, and they don't want to wait, a better idea might be to make it an asynchronous process.  Return a receipt token to the user immediately and let them know they can come back later with their receipt to pick up the result.  Provide a second method that takes in the token and returns the response.

Update:

You need to research to see if your database server has an API to allow you to cancel a process.  That's the key thing here.  If it doesn't you are out of luck.  I'm not aware of any such thing in the JDBC API, so even if it does you'll have to figure out a way to get that command to the database.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The solution you gave is a right solution but it doesn't work in my scenario. In my web application if user runs a select query to get the results which may take long time to get the result. User wants to cancel the request and want to run another query. This is just an example, there are many such scenarios we are using in our application.